# Parsing XML Response body in Apex

Tags: apex, callout, xmlparsing

I want to parse the XML body and want to capture the  url from the xml body in the list of string which i have created but i am getting Null values in the list

Respnse body:-

```
 <retours>
  <flux>
    <id>WSfv3vWBFA55L6RMQ28FOh9</id>
    <retour>
      <publication>20181026114057</publication>
      <production>20181026114057</production>
      <nature>10</nature>
      <statut>OK</statut>
      <id>AE.yxLo5IC</id>
      <url>https://telecharge.com</url>
    </retour>
    <retour>
      <publication>20181026114058</publication>
      <production>20181026114058</production>
      <nature>11</nature>
      <statut>KO</statut>
      <id>APAyxLo6K1</id>
      <url>https://telecharge1.com</url>
    </retour>
  </flux>
</retours>
```

Below Code in Apex for the parsing:

```
HttpResponse response1 = http.send(request1);
if (response1.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    //system.debug('Body ---->'+response1.getbody());  
    DOM.Document doc = response1.getBodyDocument();
    //DOM.XmlNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
    //parseXML(rootNode);
    list<string> urls=new list<string>();

    for (Dom.XmlNode node : doc.getRootElement().getChildElements()) {
        String url = node.getAttributeValue('url', '');
        //Integer score = Integer.valueOf(node.getAttributeValue('_CreditScore', ''));
        urls.add(url);
    }


    system.debug('urls.size--->'+urls.size());


}
else{
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                 response1.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response1.getStatus());
    System.debug(response1.getBody());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is on the "next level down", so your code would look something more like this:

```
for(Dom.XmlNode fluxNode: doc.getRootElement().getChildElements()) {
  for(Dom.XmlNode fluxChildNode: fluxNode.getChildElements()) {
    if(fluxChildNode.getName() == 'retour') {
      urls.add(fluxChildNode.getChildElement('url',null).getText());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the scene, but if you are wanting to have a more verbose way of deserializing XML. I would recommend the XML library here: https://github.com/zabroseric/sfdc-xml-parser

A way of using this is as follows:

```
class Retours {
    public Flux flux;
}

class Flux {
    public String id;
    public List<Retour> retour;
}

class Retour {
    public String publication;
    public String production;
    public String nature;
    public String id;
    public String url;
}

Retours retours = (Retours) XML.deserialize(
'<retours>' +
'  <flux>' +
'    <id>WSfv3vWBFA55L6RMQ28FOh9</id>' +
'    <retour>' +
'      <publication>20181026114057</publication>' +
'      <production>20181026114057</production>' +
'      <nature>10</nature>' +
'      <statut>OK</statut>' +
'      <id>AE.yxLo5IC</id>' +
'      <url>https://telecharge.com</url>' +
'    </retour>' +
'    <retour>' +
'      <publication>20181026114058</publication>' +
'      <production>20181026114058</production>' +
'      <nature>11</nature>' +
'      <statut>KO</statut>' +
'      <id>APAyxLo6K1</id>' +
'      <url>https://telecharge1.com</url>' +
'    </retour>' +
'  </flux>' +
'</retours>'
).setType(Retours.class).toObject();

Set<String> urls = new Set<String>();
for ( Retour retour : retours.flux.retour ) {
    urls.add(retour.url);
}
// {https://telecharge.com, https://telecharge1.com}
System.debug(urls);
```